# id cannot be resolved or is not a field. What does that mean and how does we fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I need help with an error. the Id cannot be resolved or is not a field.
Here is the button code: error at 10th line

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.Id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void button1Click() {
        startActivity(new Intent ("com.example.cp3.tutorial.Class2"));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                button1Click();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is our codes and we need help with the errors.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.Id.button1);
```

with

```
button1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Not `Id` it's `id`(in small letter)